# Querying GORM database by its pq.StringArray attribute

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, pq

I have the following gorm.Model and I want to Query my Postgres database to return Confessions that have a specific category in their .Categories attribute, but I have no idea how to Query inside a pq.StringArray. Is there a work-around?

```
type Confession struct {
    gorm.Model
    User       string         `json:"User"`
    Title      string         `json:"Title"`
    Body       string         `json:"Body"`
    Mood       string         `json:"Mood"`
    Categories pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:varchar(64)[]" json:"Categories"`
}
```

And here is how I tried to query, but using the LIKE operator throws an error.

```
if categories != nil {
        for _, cat := range categories {
            tx = tx.Where("Categories LIKE ?", "%"+cat+"%")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can fallback to SQL which is more efficient and understandable

Comment: i recommend to check https://medium.com/avitotech/how-to-work-with-postgres-in-go-bad2dabd13e4 , it will be easier and probably more idiomatic

Answer (score 4):

Use `<@` for array contains. You can query using `Query` function of `*sql.DB` and get `*sql.DB` using `tx.DB()` in gorm

```
sel := "SELECT * FROM confessions WHERE $1 <@ categories"
categories := []string{"cat1", "cat2"}
rows, err := tx.DB().Query(sel, pq.Array(categories))
```

Or try [Gorm Raw SQL](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Run-Raw-SQL) , but I won't sure it will work properly or not for array functions.

*References:*

- PostgreSQL Array function [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html)
- ProtgreSQL Array use in golang [here](https://www.opsdash.com/blog/postgres-arrays-golang.html)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to my problem was to use the .Where command as such

```
tx = tx.Where("categories && ?", pq.Array(categories))
```

This will return a gorm.DB so I can continue to chain actions. The && operator is to check for OVERLAPPING elements.

Comment: Did you check `<@` operator in `Where()` ? may be it creates problem.